# Decoding a base64 XML cuts off the last part

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, base64

I have a base64 encoded string, which represents an XML Schema (xsd). I decode this using Apache's Base64 utilities, put the resulting byte array into an intputsource and let an XMLSchemaCollection read this inputSource:

```
String base64String = ......
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
xmlSchemaCollection.read(inputSource, new ValidationEventHandler());
```

This gives an error:

```
XML document structure must start and end within the same entity
```

Which usually means the XML structure isn't valid. I performed two tests to see what the base64 actually holds. First is printing it out to the console:

```
System.out.println(new String(decoded,"UTF-8"));
```

In eclipse, I see my xml is suddenly cut off, like part of it is missing. However, if I use any online website, such as https://www.base64decode.org/, and I copy/paste my base64, I see the complete full xml. If I validate this xml, the validation succeeds. So I'm a bit confused as to why eclipse seemingly cuts off my xml after decoding?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing some data... can you give us a *minimal* piece of base64 which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If more than 5 chars are missing, it seems a missing `flush()`, generally called by `close()`. If the close is not missing, check the order: not closing after the output is read. 
_Also_ it could be an encoding exception being raised, and being silently discarded, breaking on some character. That should be easily seen when comparing with the original text.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this are usually indicative of a badly formatted document:

```
     XML document structures must start and end within the same entity...
```

A few things you can do to debug this:

```
1. Print out the XML document to a log and run it through some sort of XML validator.
2. Check to make sure that there are no invalid characters (ex UTF-16 characters in a UTF-8 document)
```